How can I manage nmcli ethtool properties in Ansible?
Currently I'm using the shell module to execute nmcli commands directly like this:
- name: ethtools
  shell: |
    nmcli connection modify 03da7500-2101-c722-2438-d0d006c28c73 ethtool.feature-tx-udp_tnl-segmentation off
    nmcli connection modify 03da7500-2101-c722-2438-d0d006c28c73 ethtool.feature-tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation off

But that always show a changed, so I would prefer to manage those settings in a better way. I tried with community.general.nmcli module but it looks like I can only use some properties and the none of the ethtool.* properties are manageable with that module or at least I can't figure how.
Is there any other way to manage the ethtool properties via Ansible?

If the module nmcli module – Manage Networking doesn't has the specific capability currently, you may need to enhance it. It is Open Source. Or you need to Define changed. Or write an own Custom Module for the specific tasks.

https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/8947

Have you looked at using rhel-system-roles.network?

@Squashman, yeah, looks it has it's own modules with the capability in question linux-system-roles/network/library/network_connections.py. Maybe that's also a possible solution.
